# Install mooshak 1.6.2 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apache2

I am trying to install [mooshak](https://mooshak.dcc.fc.up.pt/) to host a programming contest in my server. I tried installing mooshak in my server. The installation completed with a error message

```
could not find username in the output of info
```

When I run

```
http://localhost/~mooshak
```

I am redirecting to a page looks like a script file. The address at the address bar shows

```
http://localhost/~mooshak/cgi-bin/execute
```

I hope the script file is not executing.

Could someone please help me to install mooshak.

Comment: Do you have all the requirements and have you enabled the userdir and usexec modules in Apache?

Comment: Yes, I tried enabling userdir and suexec modules

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed this step

Enable some modules of Apache.

```
a2enmod userdir
a2enmod suexec
```

for complete guide : http://askqueries.com/install-mooshak-online-judge-ubuntu-linux/

Answer (score -1):

your problem is operating system version. some supporting tools are already there in your os so u need to install ubuntu 12.0 version then it works like that i got

Comment: Yeah it works in Ubuntu 12.0. But I don't want to change my Ubuntu Version